# Setting project QGIS variables with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

In a plugin development I have to store in a project variable the plugin version.
To test if the variable already exists I wrote:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
scope = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project)
if (scope.hasVariable('plugin_version')):
```

To set the variable I use:

```py
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project, "plugin_version", "0.1")
```

But if I try to add or set the variable through the scope (scope that I have to use to test if the variable exists) nothing happens.

```py
scope.addVariable(QgsExpressionContextScope.StaticVariable("plugin_version", "0.1", True, True, "GisFIRE version"))
scope.setVariable("gis_fire_version", "0.11")
```

Why is this behaviour happening? How can I make a variable read-only?
QGIS version is 3.10

Answer (score 3):

To read and write projects variables, you can use [QgsProject](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=qgsproject#module-QgsProject) methods [readEntry](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=qgsproject#qgis.core.QgsProject.readEntry) and [writeEntry](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=qgsproject#qgis.core.QgsProject.writeEntry).

#### Save project variable

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.writeEntry("myplugin", "version", str(3.14) )
```

#### Read project variable

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
version, version_ok = proj.readEntry("myplugin", "version", "")
if version_ok and version:
    print("version retrieved from settings as {}".format(version))
else:
    print("version not retrieved from settings")
```